# Issues with Adding UIDatePicker to UIView at Runtime

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uidatepicker

I am trying to add a UIDatePicker to a UIView when the user clicks a button. I have an animation setup that slides the UIView up from the bottom. If I add the UIDatePicker to the ViewControllers view then the DatePicker shows up correctly. However if I add the DatePicker to the UIView then the date picker doesn't show at all.

```
- (IBAction)setTimeButtonPressed:(UIButton *)sender
{
    // Creates Frame Rects for views and controls
    CGRect datePickerViewOutFrame = CGRectMake(0, 336, self.view.frame.size.width, 228);
    CGRect datePickerOutFrame = CGRectMake(0, 336, self.view.frame.size.width, 162);

    // Create View that will slide out
    UIView *datePickerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height, self.view.frame.size.width, 0)];
    datePickerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor flatCloudsColor];

    // Setup DatePicker
    UIDatePicker *datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height, self.view.frame.size.width, 0)];
    datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeTime;
    datePicker.date = [NSDate date];
    datePicker.hidden = NO;

    [self.view addSubview:datePickerView]; 
    [datePickerView addSubview:datePicker]; /* DOES NOT WORK*/

    self.datePickerView.clipsToBounds = YES;

    // Animate the views sliding out from the bottom
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                          delay:0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
                     animations:^{
                         datePicker.frame = datePickerOutFrame;
                         datePickerView.frame = datePickerViewOutFrame;

                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         // Might need later
                     }];
}
```

However, if I change the lines where I add the datePicker, it works but then I can't clip it to the bounds of the datePickerView.

```
[self.view addSubview:datePickerView];
[self.view addSubview:datePicker];  /* Works but can't clip DatePicker */
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `UIDatePickerView` frame needs to be relative to its parent view. So if you want to add it to your `datePickerView`, the frame of the `UIDatePicker` should have an origin of `0,0` instead of being based on the height of the view controller's view.

```
UIDatePicker *datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 0)];
```

Comment: AHhh, I knew I was missing something. Thanks, that did the trick!